# Not able to debug Script task in SSIS for a specific scenario

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have been searching on the net for the solution. But in my case, it is little different. I am able to debug the script task when 2 dll's are not under references. Those dll's are `System.XML` and `System.XML.Linq`. When i add these dll's under references then the package just skips every breakpoint but when i remove these two dll's and comment out the code dependent on these dll's then i am able to debug. I have tried putting `try-catch` in the `Main()`, added a breakpoint in `try` and `catch` but still it doesn't work. Any suggestions or pointers for this strange problem ?
PS: I have tried turning the option to `False` for 64 bit runtime but still the issue persists.